# Swift 4 + Xcode 9 + Could not build Objective-C module 'FBSDKLoginKit'

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, sdk

Getting an error in importing FB SDK files. I used cocoa pods to install FB SDK. I tried to create a FB LogIn Authentication module in the app. Anyone solved the issue. I just visited many stack overflow links and none can solve my issue

Comment: Do you have a bridging header file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have error setting pods, check steps with project files here:

https://github.com/mohammedjamalhadi/FBLogin

Answer (score 1):

Got a  Solution... Just Use these NEW pods

```
pod 'FacebookCore'
pod 'FacebookLogin'
```

**Earlier I used these pods**

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
```

*Also slight change in the Import Statements*

```
import FacebookLogin
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FBSDKCoreKit
```